# Streaming exception article

Tags: c++, exception

A long time ago I read an article (probably) by Herb Sutter that introduced a good/safe method of being able to stream to an exception as it was being throw. It may have been in Dr Dobbs magazine.

i.e. like this:

```
throw MyException() << "And this is my error message";
```

Does anyone remember the article and have a link too it?

**EDIT**

Actually article was written by Gigi Sayfan

Comment: Did you just create a couple of tags specifically for your question?

Comment: I just typed the tags quickly - I didnt bother to wait to see if the AJAX called resolved them or not.

Comment: Maybe [Herb Sutter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/297582/herb-sutter) himself could answer this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Practical C++ Error Handling in Hybrid Environments](http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=197003350&siteSectionName=)