# Streaming to Exception Class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a Exception base class which defines a stream function:

```
class Exception
{
public:
    template <typename TData, typename TException>
    TException& stream(const TData& data)
    {
        stream_ << data;
        return *reinterpret_cast<TException*>(this);
    }
};
```

I have a free function overloading operator<<:

```
template <typename TData>
Exception& operator<<(Exception& ex, const TData& data) {
    return ex.stream<TData, Exception>(data);
}
```

I also have dervied exceptions overloading operator<<:

```
template <typename TData>
CoffeeException& operator<<(CoffeeException& ex, const TData& data) {
    return ex.stream<TData, CoffeeException>(data);
}
```

I use this like so:

```
else {
    throw CoffeeException() << "Exception text";
}
```

When I try to use the class the compiler doesn't see the function, it just suggests the standard stream operators avaiable but doesn't note my Exception or CoffeeException free functions. Does this implementation look correct?

Comment: Why on earth do you want to use the `<<` operator instead of using a proper constructor? Also this: `return *reinterpret_cast<TException*>(this);` looks really dangerous. Don't use `reinterpret_cast` unless you really, really, *really* have to.

Comment: I **LIKE** this, even if it won't work! Good reason could be to push _data_ in a list (nicer than a varargs) or to **do not** repeat 8 constructors per each class of the hierarchy...

Comment: -1 for providing a test case that is neither short, nor complete. See http://sscce.org/. You left the following red herrings in the code, unrelated to the problem: templates, exceptions, inheritance. See [here](http://ideone.com/23nDp) for a proper testcase.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301291/streaming-exception-article and http://drdobbs.com/article/print?articleId=197003350&siteSectionName=

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like the usual problem of trying to bind a temporary to a
non-const reference.  `CoffeeException() << "Exception text"` can't bind
to your `operator<<`, because `CoffeeException()` is a temporary.  Just
make your `operator<<` a member:

```
class CoffeeException : public Exception
{
    //  ...
public:
    template <typename TData>
    CoffeeException& operator<<( TData const& data )
    {
        stream( data );
        return *this;
    }
};
```

While I'm at it: you definitely don't want the `reinterpret_cast` at the
end of `Exception::stream`.  Using the results of this cast is undefined
behavior.  It will typically work in cases of single inheritance, but
fail where multiple inheritance is involved (but even that isn't
guaranteed).  The simplest solution is what I've done above (and make
`Exception::stream` return `void`); alternatively, use `static_cast`
here (which should be legal if the inheritance is defined at the point
of instantiation).

Answer (score -1):

```
CoffeeException& operator<<(const CoffeeException& ex, const TData& data);
```

This reference must be const, because you try pass unnamed object.
You can also create temporary object to avoid using const reference.

Comment: And the reference must be non-const, because he needs to call a non-const function on it:-).

Comment: Yes, but if he wants to pass non-named object he must make it const too :-) or (it is bad practice) use const_cast inside.

Comment: It's bad practice.  Your post was fully correct, but it doesn't provide an answer to his problem.

Comment: I agree, you suggest beter solution

Comment: I need to stream to that if it's a free function so making it const doesn't solve the problem.